# Visualforce with Javascript : autocomplete is working but a field value is missing on loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, salesforce, visualforce

Since we can't use javascript in a home component anymore.
I decided to implement my javascript in a custom visualforce page.

My javascript is an autocomplete to help my users when they will start to enter a zipcode.
after their selection the BillingPostalCode and the BillingCity will be set.

I overrode the "edit page" - and i added my javascript in the  tag.
Following the documentation and my old code my autocomplete is working.

BUT when i'm loading the page the current value of my input field "BillingPostalCode" is missing :'(

Here is my visualforce page :

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="cpSearch" tabstyle="Account" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"></link>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css"></link>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete { max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto;  overflow-x: hidden;  padding-right: 20px; } 
        html .ui-autocomplete { height: 100px;}
    </style>
<script>
    var stages ;
    var staheArray; 
    $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $(function () {  
        console.log('step 0');
        $($("[id*='acc17zip']").val($("[id*='BillingPostalCode']"))).autocomplete({
            minLength: 3,
            source: function(request, response) {                       
                queryTerm = request.term; 
                console.log('step 1');
                console.log(queryTerm);            
                cpSearch.searchCP2(queryTerm,function(result, event){
                    console.log('step 2'); 
                    if(event.status) {
                        staheArray = result.toString().split("+"); 
                        response(staheArray);
                    }
                });
            }
        }); 

        $( $("[id*='acc17zip']").val($("[id*='BillingPostalCode']").val())).on("autocompleteselect", function( event, ui ){
            selectedArray = ui.item.value.split(" - ");  
            console.log('step 3');                                                                                                                
            $($("[id*='acc17zip']").val($("[id*='BillingPostalCode']").val())).val(selectedArray[0]); 
            $($("[id*='acc17city']").val($("[id*='billingcity']").val()) ).val(selectedArray[1]);
            return false;   
        });
    });
</script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton, cancelButton" 
                        hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
                        changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit">

        <apex:pageblock mode="edit" id="Doc" title="Modifier Compte">
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                    <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Sauvegarder"></apex:commandbutton>
                    <apex:commandbutton action="{!cancel}" value="Annuler"></apex:commandbutton>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Informations sur le compte">  
                <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>

                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Phone}" ></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Account.owner.Name}"></apex:outputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.fax}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Name}" required="true"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Website}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:outputfield value="{!Account.RecordType.Name}"></apex:outputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Adresse_email__c}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ParentID}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.URL_du_logo_de_la_societe__c}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.type}"></apex:inputfield>



            </apex:pageblocksection>  

            <apex:pageblocksection title="Informations supplémentaires"> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Categorie__c}"></apex:inputfield>

                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Ownership}" ></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Pays__c}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.SIRET__c}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Metier__c}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Code_APE__c}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Description}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.NumberOfEmployees}"></apex:inputfield>
            </apex:pageblocksection> 
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Coordonnées"> 
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.billingCountryCode}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ShippingCountryCode}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.billingStreet}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ShippingStreet}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.billingState}"></apex:inputfield>

                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ShippingState}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield id="acc17zip" value="{!Account.BillingPostalCode}">{!Account.BillingPostalCode}</apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.ShippingPostalCode}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield id="acc17city" value="{!Account.billingcity}"></apex:inputfield>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Shippingcity}"></apex:inputfield>


            <apex:inputfield value="{!Account.Facturation_CEDEX__c}"></apex:inputfield>
            <apex:outputtext value=""></apex:outputtext>

            </apex:pageblocksection>  
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML instead `apex` ?

Comment: I can't post the generated page (too much characters)